# vertical bar showing values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an issue and I really need your help.
I have a realtime graph with a vertical bar that moves with cursor and i want it to show the value of the graph (d.time and d.value) when the cursor points to. http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/54/ i have two series of data (data1s and data2s) that is generated randomly and I put the time in which the data is generated in "time" variable as you can see:

```css
now = new Date(Date.now() - duration);

var data1 = initialise();
var data2 = initialise();


 //Make stacked data

var data1s = data1;
var data2s = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data1s.length; i++){
data2s.push({
value:  data1s[i].value + data2[i].value,
time: data2[i].time
}  
 )};

 function initialise() {

 var arr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     var obj = {
 time: Date.now(),
 value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
};
     arr.push(obj);
 }

 return arr;
```

}

When I hover around the graph I want the tooltip show the time and value but it does not recognize it and show "undefined" since I do not know how to pass my datasets (data1s and data2s) so "mouseover function can recognize which data to show! This is how the tooltip functions are made and call from "path1" and "path2".

```
function mouseover() {
     div.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 1);
}

function mousemove(d) {



 div
  .text( d.time+ ", " + d.value)
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY ) + "px");
 }

  function mouseout() {
   div.transition()
  .duration(500)
  .style("opacity", 1e-6);
 }

var path1 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("path")
    .data([data1s])
    .attr("class", "line1")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);


  var path2 =svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("path")
    .data([data2s])
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

Do you have any idea of what to do? i think i need to add

```
svg.selectAll("path1")
.attr("opacity", 1)

 or svg.selectAll("datas1")
.attr("opacity", 1)
```

Somewhere! but i do not know how..

Thank you,

Comment: WOW! Nice app! Can you also fix your code indent to reflect its awesomeness?

Comment: Are you making fun of me ;) the tooltip is not working correctly yet. So we can not call it nice app! :P Do you have any idea or similar example to introduce to me. I really got block on it :(

Comment: Have you checked this one: http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/D4MRP/8/ (it gets the time and the value)

Comment: No I honest think it looks nice! I don't have an idea straight away how to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

Update your mouseover function as:

```
function mousemove(d) {

 div
 .text( d[0].time+ ", " + d[0].value)
 .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
 .style("top", (d3.event.pageY ) + "px");
}
```

Include the index to the object 'd'.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It shows some values but it still can not recognize the correct values. I updated what you recommend here: http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/54/ and I made another graph that shows the correct value but I do  not know how to get rid of circles! http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/52/

Comment: There has been a change in the code, some blueCircle function is there in the code which has is causing the blue dots. Please check for that.

Comment: Thank you for your time but i am not sure what you mean. Can you explain me more? If i can remove the blues circles I can reach to the correct tooltip. I do not like the way they jump up and down but at least they can recognize the correct value because of this "part: svg.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data1s)" but how can I have this part in my previous version? :( I am really blocked on this..

Comment: Nobody is here in this world to help me:(